# Is there a built and minified AureliaJS?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I don't want to get into the why / why nots of Node, jspm, Gulp etc. (they have my full buy-in) but to cut a long (boring) story short, I absolutely cannot use those lovely tools at the location i am currently at.

I want to use [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/). I just want to drop the built minified javascript library into my web application and start using it.

Where is such a package?

Many thanks,

R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an official one yet, but we are looking into it. There may be something unofficial floating around. Aurelia does require a module loader. Even though you can't use node-related tools, can we assume that you can use either system.js or require.js as a loader? (preferably system.js)

Comment: Hi, yes, that will be ok.

Comment: @Richard I _think_ (not sure though) you can use jspm to create the 'final' bundle and jspm will include everything including aurelia in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible for this time because aureliajs is only starting period and not complete for development.